# How to get a alert view wieh textinput in ios4

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I find that in ios 4 , I can not use:

```
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
```

So, how can I achieve the same effect as the code above in ios4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UITextField * textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
textField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0); //Your properties here

[alert addSubview:textField];
```

I would suggest defining the textfield globally so that you have access to it from within the whole class, and can retrieve the text input.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set an object to be the alert view's delegate and override its appearance in [willPresentAlertView:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/willPresentAlertView%3a) the way you do any other UIView (adding subviews).